# How do you suggest I approach this unique problem?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a website where I allow businesses to register what products they sell individually. Then a consumer can online and search for a product and receive a list of all the shops where it's currently selling.

Although they can upload one product at a time, I want to allow businesses to mass upload things they offer.

I was thinking of using a excel spreadsheet. Have them download the template, and then have them upload the filled in excel sheet.

Others have suggested telling them to create a CSV file, but that is counter-intuitive in my honest opinion. Most likely a secretary will be creating the product sheets and she won't have a clue about what a CSV is.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most experienced secretaries - or at least ones who've spent any time working with spreadsheets - will have a perfectly adequate understanding of what a CSV file is.

Comment: If your dealing with small companies, not everyone will have Microsoft Office...

Comment: By 'secretary' I mean a 20-26 year old who is working there for the money and not for the career.

Comment: @Sergio Tapia in which case you're stuffed, the company will grind to a halt and be out of business in two weeks time cos poor ol' Cordelia was too busy arranging her best friend's baby shower or something than paying attention to the needs of the company.

Comment: @Miles, there are plenty of free office/spreadsheet applications which can handle Excel spreadsheets, so that doesn't seem to be very restricting.

Comment: @Lucero, it may not be very restricting to someone in IT but give that to an operations person who knows nothing about computers and tell them they have to download and install a free application that will allow them to edit and save excel files. I know 90% of the people in our company would quit before they even found the download.

Comment: @Miles, I doubt that there are many offices which have absolutely no spreadsheet application installed on their computer (which usually supports the Excel file format). The point being that using the Excel format is not locking you into Excel. Any OpenOffice installation for instance can handle them just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it partly depends on the businesses. If they are medium or large businesses, they'd probably rather submit the data via a webservice anyway - then they don't have to get a human involved at all, after the initial development. They can write an application to periodically suck information from their (inevitable) database of products, and post to your web service.

If you're talking about very small companies without their own IT departments, that's less feasible, and either Excel or CSV would be a better approach. (As Caladain says, it's pretty simple to export to CSV... but you should try from a number of different spreadsheet programs as they may well have different subtleties in their export format. Things like text encoding will be important as well.)

But here's a novel idea... how about you ask some sample companies what *they* would like you to do? Presumably you have some companies in mind already - if you don't, it's potentially going to be pretty hard to make sure you're really building the right thing.

Find out how they already store their product list, and how they'd want to upload it to you. Then consider how difficult that would be, and possibly go back to them with something which is *almost* as easy for them, but a lot easier for you to implement, etc.

Comment: I've planned this for small shops with no IT and medium sized shops with a computer (but no database); it doesn't do any damage to plan ahead though, and that webservice idea is pretty great for future design. I'll keep that in mind for sure!

Answer (score 0):

While I personally don't like Excel very much, it seems to be the best accepted format to do such things (involving a manual process).

My experience is that CSV breaks easily, for instance it uses the regional settings to determine the separator which can cause incompatibilities on either the client or the server side. Also, many people just save the file in any Excel format because they just don't know the difference.

Creating the files can be pretty easily done with some XSLT (e.g. create [XMLSS format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066(office.10).aspx) files, which are "XML Spreadsheet 2003" format).

You may also want to have a look at the [Excel Data Reader on Codeplex](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) for parsing the files.

Answer (score 0):

Reading in an Excel file is actually pretty easy with ODBC.  [Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/data/mfc_database/microsoftexcel/article.php/c1131/Reading-Excel-files-using-ODBC.htm) on it.